# Android: Market design philosophy?

Tags: android, google-play

I am assuming that the Android Market app source code is closed but I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Why didn't they follow the tabbed UI design which is normally followed? (Is it only because they had more activities to display?)
2. How would I go about designing an app like this? I first set up the gallery view and attach an onClick event listener to it. But, upon receiving a click, what should I do? Do I have to use a framelayout or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to market design philosophy, but what it looks like is a vertical LinearLayout with header section containing a header with a search ImageButton, then 3 buttons and the content area which behaves like [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Mark Murphy has a great section in his book on the ViewFlipper as well as [article on Android guys](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/14/flipping-your-views/)

Comment: I remembered seeing it somewhere but couldn't remember where... Thanks!